# My locale is set, I can see € instead of $, but time still displays English months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, translation

I am doing a Rails app in French. I downloaded a fr.yml stored in config/locales and added `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr` to my application.rb. The .yml contains days and months.

Messages in pages generated by scaffold are in French, € is displayed instead of $, but it keep using English names for months with strftime (a Time function).

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= I18n.localize(Time.zone.now, :format => :short) %>
```

You can add more formats to your fr.yml

```
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d.%m.%Y"
      numeric: "%d.%m.%Y"
      short: "%e %b"
      long: "%e %B %Y, %A"
      only_day: "%e"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strftime` function isn't hooked into Rails - it's just a member of the Ruby `Time` class.  Try using Rails [localization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) instead - that should do what you're expecting.

Hope that helps!